# Doing Multiple build in Jenkins using SVN as SCM

Tags: svn, jenkins, parameterized

How can I loop an SVN folder every 3 hours, check the latest files checked in, and do the build using Jenkins CI?

I have used parameterized and I was able to select only one project at one time. But I want the Jenkins to automatically do the build based on the files when they have checked-in. Like do the one which are latest which are not yet build yet in sequence manner (first come first served).

My typical project structure:

```
<SVN URL root><branchs>Project1
<SVN URL root><branchs>Project2
<SVN URL root><branchs>Project3
```

...and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the poll scm option with the cron set for every 3hrs.

Comment: But it is only picking up the last build which was checked in .. Because i am using the parameterized.